# JDBC connection for Sybase with authentication query

Tags: sybase

I have a datasource that connects to Sybase database. I need to execute the authentication statement (SET TEMPORARY OPTION CONNECTION_AUTHENTICATION='Company....) after I connect to the database.

Is there any way of executing this statement as part of the validationQuery in the JDBC connection param so that the connection is automatically authenticated?

ANSWER:

I have managed to get answer for this !!!

This can be done by setting it in the connection url with the below parameter

SQLINITSTRING=SET TEMPORARY OPTION CONNECTION_AUTHENTICATION='Company.......

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Sybase login triggers are something you could use. Here the steps i would do:

1. Create a stored procedure which is executing your statement
2. Create a new dedicated database login
3. Assigne the login trigger to the newly created stored procedure.

More information about login triggers you find here: 
http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.sag1/html/sag1/sag1804.htm