# Coldfusion + Sybase + Authentication = SQL Anywhere Error -217

Tags: coldfusion, sybase, jtds, coldfusion-11

Migrating elderly ColdFusion + Sybase application from CF8 to CF11. Using the jTDS driver for SQL11, I can connect to the database, BUT, when I need to authentic with following code:

```html
<cfquery datasource="#application.datasource#" name="AUTH">
SET TEMPORARY OPTION CONNECTION_AUTHENTICATION='Company=zzz;Application=zzz;Signature=zzz'
</cfquery>
```

I get a CF dump, saying,

```html
 SQL Anywhere Error -217: The option 'CONNECTION_AUTHENTICATION' cannot be set from within a procedure
```

Any ideas?

More info: If I remove the above statement from application.cfm, and I attempt to log into the database as a user, if I have incorrect credentials, it tells me so. If I have CORRECT credentials, I get a CF exception dump, saying, "TDS Protocol error:Invalid packet type 0x01"

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I do not have an answer, but just to clarify ... you are saying the query above works under CF8, but not under CF11 when tested against the exact same database with the exact same JTDS driver?

Comment: Not the same driver. The old driver is circa 2007-8. The new java didn't like it.

Comment: Okay, then it is entirely possible some things have changed. Have checked the JTDS forums to verify it is supported in the current version and/or if there is another option? Also, no idea if it works, but [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12778338/jdbc-connection-for-sybase-with-authentication-query) suggests it may be supported by appending the parameter `SQLINITSTRING=SET TEMPORARY OPTION ...` to the JDBC URL.  It is a shot a the dark, but something to read up on at least.